# How to link descriptor table with multiple range to the compute shader

Tags: hlsl, compute-shader, directx-12

How to link one UAV descriptor table with a multiple ranges(u0,u1,u2) to the compute Shader

I can make a buffer for each of them and it would work but, I can't seem to figure out how to make it work using multiple ranges.

`SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex,BaseDescriptor)` Takes only these two inputs, This is how I attempted to compute it, so naturally I though I will link the three descriptors as commented below, but the app crash, so I commented the code that cause the crash.

```
ThrowIfFailed(m_pCommandAllocator->Reset());
    ThrowIfFailed(m_pCommandList->Reset(m_pCommandAllocator.Get(), m_pPipelineState["CSPSO"].Get()));

    m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootSignature(m_pCSRootSig.Get());
D3D12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE pComputeGPUHeapOffset= m_pCbvSrvDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

ID3D12DescriptorHeap* ppHeaps[] = { m_pCbvSrvDescriptorHeap.Get() };
m_pCommandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(1, ppHeaps);

    CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE desc=  CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 0, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
    m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(0, desc);
    //uncommenting those causes crash even though each point to a different descriptor
    //desc =CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 1, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
    //m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(0, desc);
    //desc = CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 2, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
    //m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(0, desc);
    m_pCommandList->Dispatch(1, 1,1);
```

Now This is written the rest of the code, First to define the descriptor table

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE uavTable;
    uavTable.Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_UAV,
        3,
        0
);
CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSigDesc(slotRootParameter.size(),
    slotRootParameter.data(),
    0,
    nullptr
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);
slotRootParameter[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &uavTable, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);
```

Then to create the main buffer

```
ThrowIfFailed(m_pDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(paddedSize + sizeof(UINT),
            D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS,
        nullptr,
        __uuidof(ID3D12Resource),
        &MainBuffer
    ));
```

and the description for each section of the buffer that I want to link to U0,U1,U2 defined in the descriptor table as

```
D3D12_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc = {};
    uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = 3000;
    uavDesc.Buffer.CounterOffsetInBytes = paddedSize;//aligned to 4096
    uavDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D12_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_NONE;
    uavDesc.Buffer.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Object1);
    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE hDescriptor(m_pCbvSrvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    
    m_pDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        &uavDesc,
        hDescriptor);

    uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = 2000;
    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 3000;
    hDescriptor.Offset(1, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
    uavDesc.Buffer.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Object2);
    m_pDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        &uavDesc,
        hDescriptor);

    uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 5000;
    hDescriptor.Offset(1, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);

    uavDesc.Buffer.StructureByteStride = sizeof(float);
    m_pDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        MainBuffer.Get(),
        &uavDesc,
        hDescriptor);
```

The paddedSize is the aligned sum of objects sizes multiplied by their buffer length

and a shader that output any values  with structures like

```
RWStructuredBuffer <Object1> FirstBuffer:register(u0);
RWStructuredBuffer<Object2> SecondBuffer:register(u1);
RWStructuredBuffer<float> ThirdBuffer:register(u2);
```

Well when I pass dummy data in the first buffer I can see that the buffer is empty and when I output anything from the buffer after the shader is done it is also empty.
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE desc=  CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 0, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(**0**, desc);
//uncommenting those causes crash even though each point to a different descriptor
//desc =CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 1, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
//m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(**1**, desc);
//desc = CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(pComputeGPUHeapOffset, 2, m_nCbvSrvDescriptorSize);
//m_pCommandList->SetComputeRootDescriptorTable(**2**, desc);
m_pCommandList->Dispatch(1, 1,1);

should give different indexes to root desc table enty in command list.